# OSX How to have ls -l sort in alphabetical order and list directories and files together

Tags: macos, terminal

I want my ls -l command to list both files and directories together rather than separating them.  I also want a case insensitive list.  For example, the following commands create the directories a and C and also the file b.txt:

```
% mkdir a C
% touch b.txt
```

Then I list them

```
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro test % ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 tyler  staff  64 Feb 12 12:06 C
drwxr-xr-x  2 tyler  staff  64 Feb 12 12:06 a
-rw-r--r--  1 tyler  staff   0 Feb 12 12:06 b.txt
```

Note how the order is C, a, b.txt.  I want it to list: a, b.txt, C (like this):

```
tyler@Tylers-MacBook-Pro test % ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 tyler  staff  64 Feb 12 12:06 a
-rw-r--r--  1 tyler  staff   0 Feb 12 12:06 b.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 tyler  staff  64 Feb 12 12:06 C
```

How do I do this case insensitive list that doesn't separate files and directories.

Comment: You want a case insensitive sort (for case sensitive, uppercase sorts before lower)..  So I don't see that as an 'ls' option (maybe macos does that). See if piping through sort (e.g. 'ls | sort -f' ) will get you closer (from 'man sort' on linux:  -f, --ignore-case fold lower case to upper case characters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combined with `sort`, this should be what's required :

```
ls -l | sort -f -k 9,9
```

`-f -k 9,9` means sort insensitively (`-f`) by 9th column (`-k 9,9`).

Comment: Thank you! I haven't been able to find this anywhere else :)